# Should patents be included in review articles?

Tags: literature-review, patents, review-articles

If so, then how should one reproduce the patented drawings in the review articles without any copyright (IPR) violation ??

Comment: yes. And do you really have to reproduce them?

Comment: Yes..I need to show the experimental setup they have used.

Comment: see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18256/how-to-reuse-a-figure-from-a-patent-is-it-free-to-reuse?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, everything relevant should be included.

For citation ruels see [How to reuse a figure from a patent? Is it free to reuse?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18256/how-to-reuse-a-figure-from-a-patent-is-it-free-to-reuse) .